# what is the difference between static SQL and dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the actual difference between static and dynamic sql? I'm not getting a clear picture about it. Is this just using the sql statements in inline queries and in stored procedures? Expecting a clear answer with example.

Answer (score 0):

static SQL statements are hard-coded but Dynamic SQL statements are constructed at runtime, for example, the application may allow users to enter their own queries. Thus, the SQL statements cannot be hard-coded into the application.

you can read more [here](http://searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/feature/Static-SQL-vs-dynamic-SQL-for-database-application-performance)